# Displaying PHP login error on the same page?

Tags: php, html, css

I have two pages. Index.php and my Login.php.

I am using dropdown menu form for logging in - when the user presses 'Sign in', the data gets sent to the Login.php. It's all okay when the password/username was correct (they get sent to the dashboard).

But how could I display an error right there, in the form? Currently when the username/password is wrong it sends you to a new blank page. I want the error to appear right there on the form.

My form:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="sr-only" for="username">Username</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" name="user_password" placeholder="Password" required>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
   </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Sign in</button>
</div>
```

My login.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "battlesql");

if (!$con) {
    echo "<div>";
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "</div>";
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['user_password'])) {

        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_name']);

        $pass = stripslashes($pass);
        $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_password']);

        $pass_hashed = hash('whirlpool', $pass);

        $select_user = "SELECT * from accounts where name='$username' AND password='$pass_hashed' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $select_user);

        $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if (!$row) {
            echo "<div>";
            echo "No existing user or wrong password.";
            echo "</div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div>";
            echo "You have been logged in.";
            echo "</div>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "MySQL error!";
    }
}
```

Comment: how to ask question [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) / [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login.php, instead of echoing "No existing user or wrong password", use this:

```
if(!$row)
      {
          die(header("location:index.php?loginFailed=true&reason=password"));
      }
```

And in your index.php, you can generate the message as:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Sign in</button>
<?php $reasons = array("password" => "Wrong Username or Password", "blank" => "You have left one or more fields blank."); if ($_GET["loginFailed"]) echo $reasons[$_GET["reason"]]; ?>
```

Comment: It works after I entered the password incorrectly (is there any way for the dropdown menu to be open after this? I only see the message after I open it). However, if I visit the page for the first time and open the dropdown-menu, it gives me an error. Notice: Undefined index: loginFailed in C:\xampp\htdocs\header.php on line 51

Comment: Where did you put this line? you have to put in where you have the echo I mentioned. Updated my answer for further explaination

Comment: I put the echo right after the button. It happens when I first time visit the page. If I visit it after the wrong password, the message is there correctly.

Comment: You mean message is printed even when you visit the page for the first time?

Comment: No, I see the error when I visit the page for the first time. If I visit it after a false password, I see the 'Wrong Username or Password' message. GIF of the situation: https://gyazo.com/61544cb56770d17dea0f83ddcd6dab3e

Comment: That's a PHP notice, rather than an error. It means that you have your error_reporting setting in your php.ini set to show notices. Try if (isset($_GET["loginFailed"])).

Comment: Please upvote and mark answer as correct if it has worked for you :) Also let me know how do you generate gifs like this

Comment: Cant chat yet (rep 3), but use a program called Gyazo and hit CTRL+Shift+G and choose the area. It automatically uploads it and copies to your clipboard.

Comment: Thanks. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using `ajax(asynchronous JavaScript and XML)`. Send login data to `login.php` from `index.php` using an `ajax` call. Read the reply the `ajax` call returns and show error/success message.

You can use the jquery `$.ajax({});` function to implement this model. If you are having trouble in implementing the `$.ajax()` function then you can read all about it **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**.

Also, if you haven't already done it, I suggest you to `encrypt` the password before sending it `login.php`.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of ways to do this, but I'll provide you with one.

Looking at your PHP code, I'm not exactly sure where your redirect to the "dashboard" is, but say you have some code like this:

```
<?php

//Fetch stuff from the database
if($fetchedUsername == $username and $fetchedPassword == $password)
{
    header("Location:/dashboard");
    return;
}

?>
```

Then, to send them back to the login form, you would just put something in the else statement:

```
<?php

if(........)
{
    //Redirect to dashboard
}
else
{
    header("Location:/login");
    return;
}

?>
```

This will send them back to the form. Now you want to show an error, so one way to do this is to set a GET variable, so in the else statement, change the header to:

```
header("Location:/login/?error=1");
```

This will let you check for the error code on the login page.

So onto your login page code. You can use `isset()` and inline-PHP echoes to print out an error directly into the form. Something like this:

```
<form>
    //Form stuff
    <?php if(isset($_GET["error"])):?>
        <div class="error">Invalid Username or Password</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

That way you can style `div.error` without worrying about an empty wrapper showing up when `$_GET["error"]` is not set.

You can also make the code to echo a bit shorter using inline PHP:

```
<?=(isset($_GET["error"])) ? "Invalid Username or Password" : ""?>
```

Comment: Great suggestion, but the only flaw is that  the login form is in a dropdown menu on my index.html not on a seperate /login page :l